# Can I make a function that returns a different type depending on a template argument, without using function parameters?

Tags: c++

This is almost what I want and it works:

```cpp
int abc(int) {
    return 5;
}

float abc(float) {
    return 8.0;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << abc(1) << "\n";
    std::cout << abc(1.0f) << "\n";
}
```

But I don't want to pass dummy parameters into the function. I want to have some sort of function and then use it like this:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << abc<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << abc<float>() << "\n";
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. You need to write a function template in order to pass template arguments.

Comment: Did you try to write such a function? The syntax looks fine; where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to define functors as in Mayolo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70311542/11082165). You can simply specialize a function template:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
T foo();

template<>
int foo() {
    return 5;
}

template<>
double foo() {
    return 8.0;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << foo<double>() << "\n";
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/a789dzjfn)!

Answer (score 5):

In your case a template variable might make more sense:

```
template <class T> constexpr T abc;

template <>
constexpr inline int abc<int> = 5;

template <>
constexpr inline float abc<float> = 8.5f;

int main()
{
    int i = abc<int>;
    float f = abc<float>;

    long x = abc<long>; // error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may do with help of if-constexpr (or runtime if in such a simple case) the exact syntax you want

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T abc() {
    if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>)
        return 5;
    else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
        return 8.0;
    else
        return {};
}
```

```
template <typename T>
T abc() {
    if (std::is_integral_v<T>)
        return 5;
    else if (std::is_floating_point_v<T>)
        return 8.0;
    else
        return {};
}
```

```
int main() {
    std::cout << abc<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << abc<float>() << "\n";
}
```